# Tomcat Web Application Thread Dump

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, thread-dump

I have a production web application (Struts, iBatis, Hibernate) that runs in Tomcat that would hang while serving requests after 6 - 7 days of running but would run fine again after doing a thread dump.

I have a hard time figuring out why that is the case.

I was just wondering whether anyone else has ever encountered something similar.

Comment: Are you sure the thread dump actually has anything to do with freeing Tomcat from hanging? That would be an interesting Heisenbugfix... 
If you can somehow make Tomcat work again by giving it a stern look, you need to put that on your resume ;-)

Comment: Have you been able to attach a profiler to the JVM to find out what's going on or, failing that, replicate the issue in a place where you could attach a profiler?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you find the cause of your problem.

I have enable JMX on tomcat 
(set these optional vm arguments when starting tomcat)
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=30188 (whatever port you want jmx to run on for tc)
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false

I then wrote a little app that monitors memory  usage (via jmx) and notifies me if the memory  usage goes over ,  say 80%.

I would then know as soon as something is starting to go wrong. Then I will get a histogram for in-memory objects (see http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html for how to get that).

At the end it turned out that one of my ejbQL queries caused a huge amount of memory being used.

Hope it might help in some way ......

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to reproduce this in a test environment. You can use [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) to stress the app. You can start tomcat using the **-verbose:gc** and **-XX:+PrintGCDetails** which will give you more insight on what is happening while GC runs. Then, when the site is not responding, you can get a thread dump and if this unblocks the site have a look at the GC details for more info.

Comment: I have the -verbose:gc and -XX:+PrintGCDetails options active. Full GC did not occur when the hang occured.